# php not able to write file on ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: php, linux, apache

Error:

```
The file temp/71076cc.php is not writable
```

Code (compiler.php):

```
$random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7);
$filePath = "temp/" . $random . ".php";
if (is_writable($filePath)) {
    if (!$fp = fopen($filePath, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }
    if (fwrite($fp, $code) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filePath)";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success, wrote ($code) to file ($filePath)";
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    echo "The file $filePath is not writable";
}
```

Dir structure of `ide` directory inside which is inside `/var/www/html`:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── compiler.php
│   ├── temp
│   │   ├── a9211d0.php
│   │   └── c7d561e.php
│   └── test.php
└── ui
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── ide.html
    └── js
        ├── ide.js
        └── lib
```

Things I tried:

1. Changing ownership to `www-data` :

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/ide/`

2. Changing permission to directory:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/ide/`

3. Changing user which apache uses (in /etc/apache2/envvars):

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=ubuntu
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=ubuntu
```

as well as

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

(Both doesnt work)

Kindly suggest any more tweaks to try.

Note:

Currently two files which are seen in temp folder was not made by running `compiler.php` code. They were made manually. However compiler.php will create such files when called from webserver.

Comment: Does PHP run inside apache httpd ? it may be running under php-fpm ? And in both cases you have to find out under what user it is running. I'd start with viewing the output of phpinfo(); in a `.php` file. Once you're sure about which user-account the code is running as, find out what the tmp folder is (could be `/tmp`, could be another), try to write into that first; then move on to trying to read filename `$infile = __FILE__;` , then to trying to write to filename `$outfile = __DIR__ . '/test.txt';`

Comment: I tried running `echo 'whoami'`. it saws user set via `APACHE_RUN_USER`. i.e. www-data first and when I changed user to ubuntu, it saw ubuntu.

Comment: i'm guessing you're looking at a script that generates your configuration or something ? Neither apache nor php normally offer dynamic usernames, and configurationchanges after the fact wouldnt affect running instances, i'd see what PHP itself says (phpinfo) about it.

Comment: I am using own temp folder made inside `/var/www/html/ide/app/temp`

Comment: ah; bit odd to have the temp folder under the webroot ? unless the webroot isn't `/var/www/html` of course. Anyway, the reason i suggested the temp folder is that that's a folder that php pretty much always has write access to already (for storing sessions and being able to accept fileuploads). If you changed it then that's all up in the air of course.

Comment: i'd find out the effective username php is running as (`phpinfo()` or `ps au`) and then verify the permissions with `sudo namei -molvx /var/www/html/ide/app/temp`

Comment: In phpinfo() : `User/Group www-data(33)/33`. and ownership of temp `drwxrwxrwx www-data www-data temp`. I also tried using /tmp folder instead of my own temp folder. Same issue.

Comment: Hello, use this way, maybe ok ! first change owner (chown) to your self userName, then check  file exist (with file_exists() php function) and create new file with touch() php function.

Comment: If you're using the above PHP code to test. Check `echo __FILE__`; to see if PHP isnt running in a chroot (it should match the real location of the .php file); and set `$filePath` to the full/absolute path, instead of relative, to rule out resolution from another workingdir.

Comment: `echo __FILE__` output: `/var/www/html/ide/app/compiler.php` . I tried setting `$filePath = "temp/" . $random . ".php";` to `$filePath = "/var/www/html/ide/app/temp/" . $random . ".php";` Still same issue.

Comment: @MohammadIlbeygi even `touch( )` is not able to create file.

Comment: Check the PHP logfile(s) for more info maybe ? could be safemode or the like; or the system audit logfiles maybe incase its like SELinux or whatever if that's enabled.